# StackOverflowException in WCF with DataContractSerializer and IsReference=true

Tags: wcf, stack-overflow

We're developing an app using EF4 POCO & WCF 4.0. We're using DataContractSerializer and we've added `IsReference=true`.

Lazy loading is disabled and the app was working fine but now on some instances of one of the entities, we see `StackOverflowException`. We've had circular references before and no problems.

Any hints on how to proceed?

Comment: You can confirm that the entity which causes that stack overflow has the proper `IsReference` attribute? i.e. you haven't missed some attributes somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm goring to write an object graph validator to tell me what classes in the object graph lack the attribute.

Comment: Ran the test.. No custom classes had any problem... I'll post the test code.

Comment: How large is your object graph?

Comment: It seems that the object graph is larger than I expected. It doesn't justify the stackoveflowexception, but seems like we can avoid the problem by avoiding such large object graphs.

Answer (score 0):

the code to test for problems related to DataContract attribute:

```
public class ObjectGraphValidator
{
    List<object> _knownObjects = new List<object>();
    Dictionary<Type, int> _encounteredCount = new Dictionary<Type, int>();
    List<Type> _nonReferenceTypes = new List<Type>();

    public void ValidateObjectGraph(object obj)
    {
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        if (_encounteredCount.ContainsKey(type))
            _encounteredCount[type]++;
        else
        {
            _encounteredCount.Add(type, 1);
            if (type.IsValueType)
                _nonReferenceTypes.Add(type);
            DataContractAttribute att = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(type, typeof(DataContractAttribute)) as DataContractAttribute;
            if (att == null || !att.IsReference)
                _nonReferenceTypes.Add(type);
        }

        if (obj.GetType().IsValueType)
            return;
        if (_knownObjects.Contains(obj))
            return;
        _knownObjects.Add(obj);
        if (obj is IEnumerable)
            foreach (object obj2 in (obj as IEnumerable))
                ValidateObjectGraph(obj2);
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
            if (property.GetIndexParameters().Count() == 0)
            {
                object value = property.GetValue(obj, null);
                if (value == null)
                    continue;
                ValidateObjectGraph(value);
            }
    }
}
```